# Hibernate multiple schemas with single Connection / DataSource / SessionFactory / TransactionManager

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, annotations, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to read and write entities with hibernate in different schemata using a single Connection / DataSource / SessionFactory / TransactionManager.

The schema names has to be configurable via application properties.
I can specify the schema in the `@Table` annotation, but it only seems to be possible to use constants.

The entities in the schemata are different.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise you not to specify a schema on entities and try to use '[SET search_path TO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-set.html)' command or its equivalent for your DBMS.
More information about multi-tenancy in Hibernate can be found in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html).

Comment: Rather than providing a link to a command(s), try adding them directly into the answer.